# how to start azure nodejs app locally

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, npm-start

I have a node.js with express azure project that I created through visual studio 2015 and it published on Azure with no problem running from vs with no issue as well.
When I try to run it through the npm command line I got an error that it can't start! I wonder if there's a configuration or any command arguments to be added to make npm able to run it.

**The error**

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\A
ppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-11T1
4_24_22_454Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is the error ? What your package.json looks like ? Did you run `npm install` before trying to start ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu Yes I do install all my required packages, I add the error thrown from the start command. The app runs with no problem if I start it in visual studio which means that no problem as I think in the package.json file!

Comment: missing script: start ... what script do you have in your package.json ?

Comment: express, jade, stylus, twitter-timeago and mysql

Comment: Those are dependencies, you don't have any [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description) ?

Comment: I know but those only what in my package.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm start` defaults to `node server.js` if start script not defined in package.json

doc : https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values

If your main file is not called server.js, try running `node yourmain.js` or adding a start entry in your package.json with `"scripts": { "start": "node yourmain.js" }`